# get app users role, name for the valid users login using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I've made stored procedure which is used to validate user login and get the role and name of the valid user. I've some confusions, please make me clear.

1. is this the optimized way to do this?
2. what is I use IF EXISTS (SELECT 1) to check for username and password and if returns true then only get the role and name of the valid user
3. @v_out_login_message returns 0, why ?

```html
create procedure p_user_login
(
 @user_name     varchar(20),
 @password     varchar(10), 
 @v_out_role    char output,
 @v_out_name    varchar(50) output,
 @v_out_login_message  int = 0 output
)
as
begin
 select @v_out_role = role, @v_out_name = name from user_information
  where user_name = @user_name and password = @password and status = 1;
 if @@rowcount = 0 
  set @v_out_login_message = 1 -- user can login
 else set @v_out_login_message = 0 -- invalid login
end
```

> declare @v_out_role   char, @v_out_name varchar(50),
>   @v_out_login_message int
>
> exec p_user_login 'admin','admin', @v_out_role output, @v_out_name
>   output, @v_out_login_message output
>
> select  @v_out_role as role, @v_out_name as name, @v_out_login_message
>   as login_message

@v_out_login_message is returning 0 why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hank already said, the `@@ROWCOUNT = 0` check should test for 1, not for 0.

As for the code, I'd probably write it like this :

```
create procedure p_user_login
(
    @user_name              varchar(20),
    @password               varchar(10),    
    @v_out_role             char output,
    @v_out_name             varchar(50) output,
    @v_out_login_message    int = 0 output
)
as
begin
    -- init
    SELECT @v_out_role = NULL,
           @v_out_name = NULL,
           @v_out_login_message = 0 -- invalid login

    -- do lookup
    select @v_out_role = role, 
           @v_out_name = name,
           @v_out_login_message = 1 -- user can login
      from user_information
     where user_name = @user_name 
       and password = @password 
       and status = 1;

end
```

=> if no valid record is found in `user_information` non of the variables gets changed and thus they retain their 'init' values.

Remark: I don't know your application, but it seems you've limited yourself to an 'exactly one role per user' scenario, is this by design?

Comment: thanks for reply and comments. **yes one user one role** in first select statement why do you again assign 0 to v_out_login_message since I've initially assigned it 0 value.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the syntax of CREATE PROCEDURE. You did *not* assign `0` to `@v_out_login_message`, instead you put a *default value* of zero to the parameter that will be used whenever you call the stored procedure without given parameter. In practice in my example, when you would not initialize the value and the user is not found in the table, then the value of the parameter would remain whatever was passed to the stored procedure by the caller! (From the manual: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330%28v=sql.105%29.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft says:

> @@ROWCOUNT Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

@@rowcount = 0 means the result of SELECT is nothing matched. So you should modify the codes as fallowing:

```
if @@rowcount > 0 
    set @v_out_login_message = 1 -- user can login
else set @v_out_login_message = 0 -- invalid login
```

Comment: thanks for the correction. I made typo mistake while coding. damn it!!! can you please answer the 1 and 2 also. thank you

Comment: About question 1., as I know, there is nothing much to optimize for performance. But, the password had better to be encrypted for security issues.  
About question 2., I don't understand what's the matter of "only get the role and name of the valid user". If you are talking about "login_message", that should be solved by question 3.